# Haskell functions to randomly order a list not working properly (Homework) beginner

Tags: list, haskell, random, shuffle

Only began using Haskell a couple of weeks ago - I am attempting to randomly shuffle a list of type Card  by splitting the list into two at a random point int eh list (depending on an array of random integers produced by the randomList function) and swapping the order of these two parts a number of times, but the output is not at all random, and the parse only seems to be happening once, pretty desperate as I need it working and the deadline is tonight!

```
randomList :: (Random a) => (a,a) -> Int -> StdGen -> [a]
randomList bnds n = take n . randomRs bnds

randomise :: [Int] -> [Card] -> [Card]
randomise [] p = p
randomise (x : xs) p = do
                    randomise xs ((drop x p) ++ (take x p))

shuffle :: Int -> [Card] -> [Card]
shuffle r p = do
          let g = mkStdGen r
          randomise(randomList (1, (length p)-1) 500 g :: [Int]) p
```

Comment: "Deadline"?  If this is homework, you need to tag it as such.  Moreover, could you explain what you mean by "not at all random"?  How are you determining the randomness of the output?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  It can be pretty readily adapted to linked lists.

Comment: It's coursework, a random array of integers is fed into randomise, the length of this array is 500, the list of cards should be split and reordered 500 times

Comment: @RyanConnolly: And *is* it split & reordered 500 times?  If not, how can you tell?

Comment: Try working through with pen and paper what `randomise [3,4,14,20] ['A'..'Z']` evaluates to (imagine `type Card = Char` for this exercise).

Comment: @dave4420 you're brilliant, cheers, no clue where i got my logic from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a random number of permutations on your list. You can do it like:

```
import System.Random
import Data.List

shuffle xs = do
    gen <- getStdGen
    let (permNum,newGen) = randomR (0,fac (length xs) -1) gen
    return $ permutation permNum xs
```

`permutation` makes `n` permutations on the (assumed sorted) list `xs`. When randomizing, `xs` need not be sorted however.

`fac` is just an implementation of the factorial function.

`shuffle` makes a random number and applies that many permutations to `xs`.

It's a bit different from what you are trying to do, but it works wonders. I assumed you didn't need to explicitly use your proposed method. You will have to implement `permutation` and `fac` yourself though.

For help on `permutation`, you could look [here](http://tafakuri.net/?p=68). It's a description to solve a Project Euler Problem, but you could use the same procedure to make `n` permutations.

EDIT: I don't know if anyone cares anymore, but I found another way to do it WAY easier:

```
import System.Random

randPerm :: StdGen -> [a] -> [a]
randPerm _ []   = []
randPerm gen xs = let (n,newGen) = randomR (0,length xs -1) gen
                      front = xs !! n
                  in  front : randPerm newGen (take n xs ++ drop (n+1) xs)
```

Comment: It's good practice to answer homework questions with hints and clues, rather than providing a complete solution.

Comment: Well, I just thought that it didn't matter since the deadline has expired. Fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but a small improvement over the suggested solution is to use splitAt instead of take & drop:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> StdGen -> [a]
shuffle []   _   = []
shuffle list generator = let (index,newGenerator) = randomR (0,length list -1) generator
                             (listUntilIndex, element:listAfterIndex) = splitAt index list
                         in  element : shuffle (listUntilIndex ++ listAfterIndex) newGenerator
```